# Determining real solutions - Square Root used

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am revising for a test next week based around simple algebra and I appreciate this question may not be the most difficult however I am struggling.

The question is:

Determine all real solutions in the following

$-\frac{1}{\:\sqrt{3x+5}}+\frac{1}{x}=0$

I am unsure of how to get the answer without using a calculator (or a lot of working) - the answer stated is:

$x=\frac{3+\sqrt{29}}{2}$

I know one way to find this answer is by rearranging and squaring and plugging in:

$x=\frac{3+\sqrt{29}}{2}$

and

$x=\frac{3-\sqrt{29}}{2}$

to find that only the first answer works.

However if I can help it, I dont wish to have to plug the answer back in. Is there a way of finding the answer in a more efficient manner (such as determining that x should be above or below a certain value?)

Thanks

Comment: As has been pointed out by Scientifica, a solution of $x=\sqrt{3x+5}$ cannot be negative, so one of the numbers produced by your calculation cannot work. The surviving candidate is positive, so for it we have $\sqrt{3x+5}=x$ if and only if $3x+5=x^2$, so squaring did not produce a spurious root. Plugging in is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to find solutions, you are going in one sense of the material conditional $\Rightarrow$. After fiding solutions, or better call them "elected to be solutions", you must see if they are so by going back to the inequality to have $\Leftarrow$. In fact you loose your $\Leftarrow$ while solving when you have $A=B\Rightarrow A^2=B^2$ because $A^2=B^2\Rightarrow A =B$ isn't always true because it's "or $A=-B$". Well you can simply say $x=\sqrt{3x+5}$ so $x\ge 0$ and then when you find the two "elected solutions" the number $\dfrac{3-\sqrt{29}}{2}<0$ because $\sqrt{9}<\sqrt{29}$ so it even can't be a solution, so you just need to check $\dfrac{3+\sqrt{29}}{2}>0$ if it's a solution.